# Functors when should I use them whats their intended use

Tags: c#, .net, generics, lambda, functor

I Just can't seem to wrap my head around them.

As I understand it's dynamically adding logic to a class. Are classes within the framework prepared for this?

Why should I just extend the class and add the functionality to it in the extension. I would be globally accessible and afaik much easier to maintain.

I've Read there are 4 functor types:

Comparer
Closure
Predicate
Transformer

We should probably Handle each one of them.

p.s. is there something like it in vb?

So I can state I think that lambda expressions are functors. This clears up things for me a bit :) (hehe)

- Lambda expressions are functors?
- Anonymous functions are functors?

But I asked this question because I ran into another type of fucntors namely these ones:

```
delegate void FunctorDelegate(int value);
class Addition {
    FunctorDelegate _delegate;

    public Addition AddDelegate(FunctorDelegate deleg) {
        _delegate += deleg;
        return this;
    }
    public int AddAllElements(IList< int> list) {
        int runningTotal = 0;
        foreach( int value in list) {
            runningTotal += value;
            _delegate(value);
        }
        return runningTotal;
    }
}
```

And then calling it with this:

```
 int runningTotal = new Addition()
     .AddDelegate(new FunctorDelegate(
                     delegate(int value) {
                         if ((value % 2) == 1) {
                             runningOddTotal += value;
                         }
                     }))
    .AddDelegate(new FunctorDelegate(
                     delegate(int value) {
                         if ((value % 2) == 0) {
                             runningEvenTotal += value;
                         }
                     }))
    .AddAllElements(list);
```

So no fancy lambda style things.

Now I have this example but it isn't at all clear why this is a "good" solution.

**Are delegates (functors) used as lambda expressions or anonymous methods "in most cases" just there as a shortcut for the programmer? There are as far as I can see only a few cases where they're actually the prefered choice for a problem.**

Comment: I'm inclined to say that it *isn't* a good solution; perhaps they were trying to show *potential* usage, rather than typical usage. The only "nice" thing (and I'm being generous here) about that code is that it only enumerates the data once - but there are other answers to this. For example, PushLINQ (MiscUtil) allows multiple aggregates on a "once only" data feed with (IMO) a lot more elegance.

Comment: hehe this code was to show it's potential usage but did even a bad job at that :). I posted it to explain the "other" type of functor (anonymous methos) I ran into. But it wasn't/isn't clear where in my daily life this would become "THE" solution. Fredrik asnwered that a bit.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you're confusing terms from different languages. You seem to be using "Functor" in the C++ or Java sense, e.g. [see the wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object). In C++, it's an object of a class that overloads the function-call operator, so it can be used as a function but with state.

This is logically the same thing as a delegate bound to an instance method in C# (or any .NET language).

There are three ways to write such a thing. First, you can write an ordinary method, and then assign the name of the method to a delegate variable.

```
void MyMethod() { Console.WriteLine("Hi!"); }

void Foo()
{
    Action a = MyMethod;
    a();
}
```

Second, you can use anonymous method syntax, introduced in C# 2.0:

```
void Foo()
{
    Action a = delegate { Console.WriteLine("Hi!"); }
    a();
}
```

Thirdly, you can use lambda syntax, introduced in C# 3.0:

```
void Foo()
{
    Action a = () => Console.WriteLine("Hi!");
    a();
}
```

The advantage of the last two is that the body of the method can read and write local variables in the containing method.

The advantage of lambda syntax over anon-methods are that it is more succinct and it does type inference on parameters.

**Update:** The advantage of anon-methods (`delegate` keyword) over lambdas is that you can omit the parameters altogether if you don't need them:

```
// correct way using lambda
button.Click += (sender, eventArgs) => MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");

// compile error - wrong number of arguments
button.Click += () => MessageBox.Show("Clicked!");

// anon method, omitting arguments, works fine
button.Click += delegate { MessageBox.Show("Clicked!"); };
```

I know of only one situation where this is worth knowing, which is when initializing an event so that you don't have to check for `null` before firing it:

```
event EventHandler Birthday = delegate { };
```

Avoids a lot of nonsense elsewhere.

Finally, you mention that there are four kinds of functor. In fact there are an infinity of possibly delegate types, although some authors may have their favourites and there obviously will be some common patterns. An `Action` or `Command` takes no parameters and returns `void`, and a predicate takes an instance of some type and returns `true` or `false`.

In C# 3.0, you can whip up a delegate with up to four parameters of any types you like:

```
Func<string, int, double> f;  // takes a string and an in, returns a double
```

**Re: Updated Question**

You ask (I think) if there are many use cases for lambdas. There are more than can possibly be listed!

You most often see them in the middle of larger expressions that operate on sequences (lists computed on-the-fly). Suppose I have a list of people, and I want a list of people exactly forty years old:

```
var exactlyForty = people.Where(person => person.Age == 40);
```

The `Where` method is an extension method on the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, where `T` in this case is some kind of `Person` class.

This is known in .NET as "Linq to Objects", but known elsewhere as pure functional programming on sequences or streams or "lazy" lists (all different names for the same thing).

Comment: right. Now we're getting somewhere. So functors (as in the name) do not really exsist in .net they are delegates.
The succinctness of lambda is I think personal flavour I don't mind typing more to keep it readable. But the type inferance is ever so cool and is a definite pro for the lambda flavour.
 
I'll add a bit more to my question.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, I added a bonus update about omitting arguments to delegate.

Comment: Thanks :) I think we did a great job clearing this up and making a case for lambdas, delegates and anonymous functions. Where I work they're v. scared of this stuff. But hey you can't stop the future right. :).

Answer (score 7):

In .NET terms, I *think* what you are describing is the `Delegate` - and it exists in all of .NET, not just C#.

I'm not sure that a "closure" would a "type" in the same was as a comparer/predicate/transformer, since in C# terms a closure is simply an implementation detail but can **be** any of those three.

In .NET, delegates are used in two main ways:

- as the eventing mechanism
- to provide functional-style programming

The first is important, but it sounds like you are more interested in the second. In reality, they operate much like single-method interfaces... consider:

```
List<int> vals = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
List<int> evenVals = vals.FindAll(i => i % 2 == 0); // predicate
List<string> valsAsStrings = vals.ConvertAll(i => i.ToString()); // transformer
// sort descending
vals.Sort((x, y) => y.CompareTo(x)); // comparer
```

A closure is more where we bring additional scope from **outside** the delegate *into* the delegate:

```
int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // perhaps 6
List<int> limited = vals.FindAll(i => i <= max);
```

here the `max` is captured into the delegate as a closure.

Re "Are classes within the framework prepaired for this?" - many are, and LINQ goes a *long* way to allowing this even wider. LINQ provides extension methods over (for example) all of `IEnumerable<T>` - meaning that collections *without* delegate-based access aquire them for free:

```
int[] data = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
var oddData = data.Where( i => i % 2 == 1 );
var descending = data.OrderBy(i => -i);
var asStrings = data.Select(i => i.ToString());
```

Here the `Where` and `OrderBy` methods are LINQ extension methods that take delegates.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.I knew they have things to do with delegates. I don't think it possible to do any serious c# programming without running into delegates. I've mainly used them for async functions and events. But I asked this question because I ran into another form of functors. I didn't know the linq like predicate stuff were functors aswell. I'll update the question about the styles.

Comment: The LINQ stuff is... complicated ;-p The extension methods on IEnumerable<T> use delegates, but the extension methods on IQueryable<T> use Expression trees, which look identical to the caller (assuming they are using either lambda statements or query syntax) but which are **completely, 100%** different ;-p

Comment: So only part of the linq lamba expression things are functors. riiiight. :) I Love the guy that thought that was a good idea :P It works, and I use the stuff daily, but how or why it works only a few people really know :)

Comment: No... that isn't it; a lambda-delegate is a functor, as is an anonymous method, as is a regular method. The difference is the subtle difference between Func<...> and Expression<Func<...>>: http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/explaining-expression.html

Comment: That is a very interesting post although it probably requires a bit more reading to fully understand it. Like you said you covered a lot in a small(ish) space. But it's definately clearer now what and why functors are.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting with terminology; my spontaneous interpretation of the term "Functor" was that it referred to anonymous methods. So that will be my take on it.

These are some of my typical uses:

Comparisons (usually for sorting a list):

```
List<int> ints = new List<int>();
ints.AddRange(new int[] { 9, 5, 7, 4, 3, 5, 3 });
ints.Sort(new Comparison<int>(delegate(int x, int y)
    {
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }));
// yes I am aware the ints.Sort() would yield the same result, but hey, it's just
// a conceptual code sample ;o)

// and the shorter .NET 3.5 version:
ints.Sort((x, y) =>
{
    return x.CompareTo(y);
});
```

I will use this approach for comparisons, rather than having it in its own method an using a delegate for that method, in the cases where this particular sort happens in one place only. If it is likely that I will want to use the same comparison somewhere else, it gets to live in its own, reusable method.

Another of my fairly common uses is in unit testing, when the test relies on some event being raised. I have found that to be essential when unit testing workflows in Workflow Foundation:

```
WorkflowRuntime runtime = WorkflowHost.Runtime;  
WorkflowInstance instance = runtime.CreateWorkflow(typeof(CreateFile)); 
EventHandler<WorkflowEventArgs> WorkflowIdledHandler = delegate(object sender, WorkflowEventArgs e)
{
    // get the ICreateFileService instance from the runtime  
    ISomeWorkflowService service = WorkflowHost.Runtime.GetService<ISomeWorkflowService>();

    // set the desired file content  
    service.DoSomeWork(instance.InstanceId, inputData);
};  
// attach event handler
runtime.WorkflowIdled += WorkflowIdledHandler;  

instance.Start();  
// perform the test, and then detach the event handler
runtime.WorkflowIdled -= WorkflowIdledHandler;
```

In this case it is simpler to have the event handler declared as anonymous methods since it uses the `instance` variable that is defined in the unit test method scope. Had I intstead opted to implelment the event handler as its own separate method I would also need to figure out a way for it to pick up `instance`, probably by introducing a class level member, which would not seem like a perfect design in a unit test class.

There are more cases where I find this in my code, but they usually have one or two things in common:

- *I have no interest in referencing that piece of code from anywhere else than in that particular place*.
- *The method needs access to data that would be out of the scope for a regular method*

Comment: This look more like what I initially thought were functors. I think the last two sentances of your post really hit ground with me this explains why I would use functors/anonymousmethods/lambdaexpression.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is that a functor is a type of mathematical object, and is "reified" by different languages in different ways.  For example, suppose that you have a "container" object that stores a bunch of other objects of the same type.  (For example, a set or array)  Then, if your language had a method that let you 'map' over the container, so that you could call a method on each object in the container, then the **container would be a functor**.

In other words, a functor is a container with a method that lets you pass a method to its contained things.

Every language has its own way of doing this, and they sometimes conflate the usage.  For example, C++ uses function pointers to represent the "passing in" of a method, and calls the function pointer a "functor."  Delegates are just a handle on methods that you can pass in.  You are using the terminology "incorrectly", just like C++ does.

Haskell gets it right.  You declare that a type implements the functor interface, and then you get the mapping method.

Functions (like lambdas) are functors too, but it can be kind of hard to think of a function as a "container".  In short, a function is a "container" around a return value, constructed in such a way that the return value (possibly) depends on the function's arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you mean Lambda Expressions. Those are Small Functions you can write very quickly, and they have the characteristic "=>" Operator. These are a new Feature of C# 3.0.

This Example will be a classic Transformer; to use one we need a delegate to define the signature for the Lambda Function.

```
delegate int Transformer(int i);
```

Now Declare a Lambda with this delegate:

```
Transformer sqr = x => x * x;
```

We can use it like a normal function:

```
Console.WriteLine(sqr(3)); //9
```

These are used in LINQ Queries a lot, for example to Sort (Comparer), to Search through (Predicate).

The book "C# Pocket Reference" (apart from beign the best around in my opinion, has a very good part on Lambdas. (ISBN  978-0-596-51922-3 )

Comment: As an aside - with .NET 3.5 it would be more common to use a Func<int,int> than to define a new Transformer delegate to do the same thing...

Comment: It's not only lambda expressions. As we've established (I think) only part or the lambda expressions are actually functors.