# Do functors have an equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, functor

Is there an equivalent to `Functors` in **C#**?

**C#** has `Func<,>`, `delegate`s and *anonymous methods* but aren't all of these *pointers* to a method?

The **C++** `Functor` is a *class* and not a *pointer to a method*.

Comment: This answer might help http://stackoverflow.com/a/974639/187697

Comment: I saw that but they were being specific to his question and not general.

Comment: That answer has a list of approximates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> C# has Func<,>, delegates and anonymous methods **but aren't all of these pointers to a method?**

No. Even C# delegates are classes, implemented by the compiler for you. These generated classes (for delegates) are derived from [`MulticastDelegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx) which in turn derives from [`Delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.aspx).

In short, a delegate is a syntactic sugar for a class generated by compiler.

Comment: Ok.  Would those be similar to Functors than?

Comment: @4thSpace: "similar" in what sense? In C#, you cannot overload `operator()`. So if you mean that, then it is not similar. C# is a different language, it does few things differently, achieves them differently.

Comment: operator()?  Are you referring to something different than this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467(v=vs.71).aspx?

Comment: @4thSpace:  If you don't know `operator()`, then how do you know what functor is in C++? What makes a class functor in c++?

Comment: C++: Because the class implements operator().

Comment: @4thSpace: Yes, and C# doesn't. In fact, C# doesn't allow you to overload `operator()`. Is this clear enough now?

Comment: Delegates *are* similar to functors in the sense that the syntax to call the pointed-to method looks just like a normal function call.

Comment: This is purely subjective _C# is a different language, it does few things differently, achieves them differently._ and one of the worst arguments that doesn't explain anything.

Answer (score 5):

Both *lambdas* (`Func<>`, `Action<>`) and *delegates* (named as well as anonymous) are classes.

If you need a *pointer to method* (to pass it into unsafe code, for instance) you should use *marshalling*:

```
IntPtr pFunc = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(myDelegate);
```